# How to install `cv2` correctly for `Raspbian Jessie`?

Tags: opencv, python-3.4

When I tried to install opencv2 in python 3.4.2 in rasbian jessie, the following error occured.

```
pip3 install python3-opencv
```

> Collecting python3-opencv
>        Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python3-opencv (from versions: )
>      No matching distribution found for python3-opencv

I have also tried:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-opencv
```

It also shows the same error.

Comment: `pip3 install opencv-contrib-python`

Comment: it also shows: pip3 install opencv-contrib-python
Collecting opencv-contrib-python
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-contrib-python (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for opencv-contrib-python

Comment: Sorry, I thought you want to install it on `ubuntu`, while actually you want  it for `rasbian jessie`. Maybe you should compile by yourself, I'm not good at this.

Comment: [raspbian-stretch-install-opencv-3-python-on-your-raspberry-pi](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/09/04/raspbian-stretch-install-opencv-3-python-on-your-raspberry-pi/)

Comment: I wanted it for Raspbian Jessie

Comment: Yeah, I rewrite you question title to enhence it. And show a link that maybe help.

Comment: did you solve this ?